# Reactor doesn't throw NPEs. Is it still a Reactive Streams implementation?

Tags: project-reactor, reactive-streams

Here's what I found in the [Reactive Streams specification](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#2-subscriber-code)

> Calling onSubscribe, onNext, onError or onComplete MUST return normally except when any provided parameter is null in which case it MUST **throw** a java.lang.NullPointerException to the caller, for all other situations the only legal way for a Subscriber to signal failure is by cancelling its Subscription.

I checked it

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        Mono.just("some-string")
                .map(this::makeNull)
                .map(String::toUpperCase) // here it should throw
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private String makeNull(String string) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
[main] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators -- Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper [com.example.dynamicgateway.misc.GenericTest$$Lambda$377/0x0000000800cd8af8] returned a null value.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper [com.example.dynamicgateway.misc.GenericTest$$Lambda$377/0x0000000800cd8af8] returned a null value.
```

It looks like an exception but actually it's just a log message

Is Project Reactor a bona fide Reactive Streams implementation? Or did it find some loophole in the spec and can legally avoid throwing NPEs on null arguments under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactor does throw a NullPointerException when trying to use null values.

The reason why the exception is not launched in your test method is because `subscribe` triggers the flow asynchronously. **The error is not raised in the method, but in a background worker**. Therefore, it is only logged by the thread that run the pipeline.

In the context of tests, you should use `reactor-test` module and its `StepVerifier` class, that listens to the events on the pipeline to test.

We can write your example as follow:

```java
@Test
public void mapNullShouldThrowError() {
    var myMono = Mono.just("test")
            .<String>map(it -> null)
            .map(String::toUpperCase);

    StepVerifier.create(myMono)
            .expectError(NullPointerException.class)
            .verify();
}
```

You can also test this assertion by using `block()` instead of `subscribe`. Although it should be avoided if possible, in this case you can try it: block will cause the error to be propagated in the test method.